# Pathological expression for field strength contractions in a curved background

Tags: symbolic, physics, tensors

I am trying to define in Mathematica the quantity $\star F^{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$, where $F_{\mu\nu}=\nabla_\mu A_\nu-\nabla_\nu A_\mu+\left[A_\mu,A_\nu\right]$. Here $\nabla$ is the spacetime covariant derivative of the metric $ds^2=-dt^2+R^2dr^2+L^2d\phi^2$. In the field strength $F_{\mu\nu}$ the gauge field $A_\mu$ is defined as $A=A^j_\mu t_j dx^\mu$ where $t_j=i\sigma_j$ with $\sigma_j$ the $j=1,2,3$ Pauli matrices and $$A_\mu=\lambda(x) U^{-1}\partial_\mu U\,\quad U(x)=\cos[\alpha(x)]I_{2\times 2}+\sin[\alpha(x)]n^it_i,$$ with $$n^1=\sin\left[\Theta(x)\right]\cos\left[\Phi(x)\right],\quad n^2=\sin\left[\Theta(x)\right]\sin\left[\Phi(x)\right],\quad n^3=\cos\left[\Theta(x)\right].$$ When I compute $\star F^\mu$ with the previous functions, I obtain an expression of the form `Sin[1[t, r, \[Phi]]]` or `Sin[2 1[t, r, \[Phi]]]`, which seems pathological. This is my question.

Let me show my code below and explain it, step by step.

First, the spacetime is defined as

```
Coords = {t, r, \[Phi]};
    gdd = {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, \[Rho]^2, 0}, {0, 0, L^2}}
    gUU = Inverse[gdd]
    dimM = Dimensions[gdd][[1]]
```

Then I define the General Relativity tensors, i.e., Christoffel Symbols, Riemann tensors and so on (this is not important, however, I put them for completeness and perhaps this code will be helpful for somebody)

```
\[CapitalGamma]Udd = 
      1/2 Table[
         Sum[gUU[[\[Mu] + 1, \[Tau] + 
             1]] (D[gdd[[\[Lambda] + 1, \[Tau] + 1]], 
              Coords[[\[Nu] + 1]]] + 
             D[gdd[[\[Nu] + 1, \[Tau] + 1]], Coords[[\[Lambda] + 1]]] - 
             D[gdd[[\[Nu] + 1, \[Lambda] + 1]], 
              Coords[[\[Tau] + 1]]]), {\[Tau], 0, dimM - 1}], {\[Mu], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Nu], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Lambda], 0, dimM - 1}] // 
       Simplify;
    RUddd = Table[
         D[\[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Alpha] + 1, \[Beta] + 1, \[Delta] + 1]], 
          Coords[[\[Gamma] + 1]]], {\[Alpha], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Gamma], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Delta], 0, dimM - 1}] - 
        Table[D[\[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Alpha] + 1, \[Beta] + 1, \[Gamma] + 
            1]], Coords[[\[Delta] + 1]]], {\[Alpha], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Beta], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Gamma], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Delta], 0, dimM - 1}] + 
        Table[Sum[\[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Mu] + 1, \[Beta] + 1, \[Delta] + 
             1]] \[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Alpha] + 1, \[Mu] + 1, \[Gamma] + 
             1]], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}], {\[Alpha], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Beta], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Gamma], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Delta], 0, dimM - 1}] - 
        Table[Sum[\[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Mu] + 1, \[Beta] + 1, \[Gamma] + 
             1]] \[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Alpha] + 1, \[Mu] + 1, \[Delta] + 
             1]], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}], {\[Alpha], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Beta], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Gamma], 0, 
          dimM - 1}, {\[Delta], 0, dimM - 1}] // Simplify;
    Rdd = Table[
        Sum[RUddd[[\[Alpha] + 1, \[Beta] + 1, \[Alpha] + 1, \[Delta] + 
           1]], {\[Alpha], 0, dimM - 1}], {\[Beta], 0, 
         dimM - 1}, {\[Delta], 0, dimM - 1}] // Simplify;
    R = Sum[gUU[[\[Beta] + 1, \[Delta] + 1]] Rdd[[\[Beta] + 1, \[Delta] + 
           1]], {\[Beta], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Delta], 0, dimM - 1}] // 
       Simplify;
    Einsteindd = Rdd - 1/2 gdd R;
```

Here begins the important part. I define the Pauli matrices, the normal vector $n^i$, the matrix $U$, its inverse and the gauge field $A_\mu$

```
ColorCoords = {t, r, \[Phi]};
dimC = 3;
t1 = I PauliMatrix[1];
t2 = I PauliMatrix[2];
t3 = I PauliMatrix[3];
td = {{t1}, {t2}, {t3}};
tdd = -(1/2) Table[
    Tr[td[[a + 1, 1]].td[[b + 1, 1]]], {a, 0, dimC - 1}, {b, 0, 
     dimC - 1}];
tUU = Inverse[tdd];
tU = Sum[Table[tUU[[a + 1, b + 1]] td[[b + 1]], {b, 0, dimC - 1}], {a,
     0, dimC - 1}];
nU = {{Sin[\[CapitalTheta][t, r, \[Phi]]] Cos[\[CapitalPhi][t, 
       r, \[Phi]]]}, {Sin[\[CapitalTheta][t, 
       r, \[Phi]]] Sin[\[CapitalPhi][t, 
       r, \[Phi]]]}, {Cos[\[CapitalTheta][t, r, \[Phi]]]}};
nd = Table[
   Sum[nU[[a + 1]] tdd[[a + 1, b + 1]], {a, 0, dimC - 1}], {b, 0, 
    dimC - 1}];
U = Cos[\[Alpha][t, r, \[Phi]]] IdentityMatrix[2] + 
    Sin[\[Alpha][t, r, \[Phi]]] Sum[
      nU[[a + 1, 1]] td[[a + 1, 1]], {a, 0, dimC - 1}] // Simplify;
Uinv = Inverse[U] // Simplify;
Ad = \[Lambda][t, r, \[Phi]] Table[
     Uinv.D[U, ColorCoords[[\[Mu] + 1]]], {\[Mu], 0, dimC - 1}] // 
   FullSimplify;
```

Defining now the covariant derivative of the gauge field $\nabla_\mu A_\nu$

```
covDAd = Table[D[Ad, Coords[[\[Mu] + 1]]], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}] - 
    Sum[Table[\[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Lambda]1 + 1, \[Mu] + 1, \[Nu] + 
          1]] Ad[[\[Lambda]1 + 1]], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Nu], 0, 
       dimM - 1}], {\[Lambda]1, 0, dimM - 1}] // Simplify;
```

we are now in a position to define the field strength

```
Fdd = covDAd - Transpose[covDAd] + 
   Table[Ad[[\[Mu] + 1]].Ad[[\[Nu] + 1]] - 
     Ad[[\[Nu] + 1]].Ad[[\[Mu] + 1]], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Nu], 0,
      dimM - 1}];
```

Now we are going to define the components of the dual field strength $*F^\mu$. In three-dimensions, the Levi-Civita symbol is defined as

```
LCd = Normal[LeviCivitaTensor[3]];
LCU = Normal[-LeviCivitaTensor[3]];
\[Epsilon]UUU = LCU;
\[Epsilon]ddd = LCd;
```

then, we define $\star F^\mu=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$ as

```
dualFU = 1/
   2 Table[Sum[\[Epsilon]UUU[[\[Mu] + 1, \[Alpha] + 1, \[Beta] + 
         1]] Fdd[[\[Alpha] + 1, \[Beta] + 1]], {\[Alpha], 0, 
      dimM - 1}, {\[Beta], 0, dimM - 1}], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}];
```

Observe that if we compute `dualFU[[1, 1]]` we quickly obtain terms of the form `Cos[2 1[t, r, \[Phi]]]`, `Sin[2 1[t, r, \[Phi]]]` and so on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to run your code, but ran into errors due to nU and tdd not being defined, causing Part to complain . These affect the evaluation of nd and U . If I push on anyway and evaluate the remaining terms, I get dualFU = {{{0,0},{0,0}},{{0,0},{0,0}},{{0,0},{0,0}}} and dualFU[[1,1]] = {0,0}. It's likely the missing terms will alter this result however, since you appear to compute derivatives of U, etc.

Comment: I edited the question and added the definition of tdd, so tell me now if you are able to compile the code.

Comment: There are typos due to mixture of definition  `Ad = \[Lambda][t, r, \[Phi]] ...` and index $\lambda$ in `covDAd`.  Try `covDAd = 
  Table[D[Ad, Coords[[\[Mu] + 1]]], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}] - 
    Sum[Table[\[CapitalGamma]Udd[[\[Lambda]1 + 1, \[Mu] + 1, \[Nu] + 
          1]] Ad[[\[Lambda]1 + 1]], {\[Mu], 0, dimM - 1}, {\[Nu], 0, 
       dimM - 1}], {\[Lambda]1, 0, dimM - 1}] // Simplify;`

Comment: Ok, I corrected the typos, but the error persists in dualFU.

Comment: Maybe you need to refresh kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a fresh kernel, I can duplicate your results. One thing I noticed is that you appear to use \[Alpha][t,r,[Phi]] in U, but also sum over \[Alpha],\[Beta]. I tried changing the summation indices in dualFU to a,b, and the problem seems to go away. I.e. try

```
    dualFU = 
      1/2 Table[
           Sum[\[Epsilon]UUU[[\[Mu] + 1, a + 1, b + 1]] Fdd[[a + 1, 
              b + 1]], {a, 0, dimM - 1}, {b, 0, dimM - 1}], {\[Mu], 0, dimM-1}]
```

I think Sum/Table are not only replacing the indices, but also the \[Alpha][t,r,\[Phi]] expression heads with \[Alpha] -> 0,1,2,3 in the sums. Since you use the summation indices in several places, it might be easier to just replace \[Alpha][t,r,\[Phi]] with something else which doesn't clash.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, it solved my question.